# Determine if a given url (from a string) is from my domain or not

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to check from c# code if a given url is from my domain or not, in order to add the "nofollow" and "target _Blank" attributes for external links.

When i talk about external links i refer to any link outside my domain.

By default it does not have that attributes. I tried a lot of stuff, basically this is the part i need to fix:

```
 public void PrepareLink(HtmlTag tag)
    {
        string url = tag.attributes["href"];

        if (PrepareLink != null)
        {
            if (it is from an external site???)
            {
                tag.attributes["rel"] = "nofollow";
                tag.attributes["target"] = "_blank";
            }                
        }
```

Edit: 
things i've tried:

```
                string dominioLink = new Uri(url).Host.ToLower();

                if (!dominioLink.Contains(myDomainURL))
                {
                    tag.attributes["rel"] = "nofollow";
                    tag.attributes["target"] = "_blank";
                }
```

Which has the issue that dont take in mind subdomains

i.e. if a link created is http://www.mydomain.com.anotherfakedomain.com, it will return true and work well.

I've looked in every Uri property but didn't seem to contains the base domain.

I'm currently using .NET Core 2.0.

thankS! please if you need any other data just let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you extract the domain from the email? Compare it to your own domain? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: hi @mason, i've updated the post. Basically I tried with the URI one

Comment: So it it doesnt take into account subdomain, why not parse it out? This is basic string manipulation.

Comment: "didn't seem to contains the base domain" - because host names don't have concept of "Base domain" or "subdomain" or anything in between... As soon as you figure out what you want (most likely one string [EndsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith) another) you should have a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Uri.Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=netframework-4.8) property to obtain the domain from a URL string, then compare it to your own. I suggest using a case-insensitive match.

```
var url = tag.attributes["href"];
var uri = new Uri(url);
var match = uri.Host.Equals(myDomain, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: this sounds promising. please let me try it and i'll get back to you. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You can also use a RegEx and Regex.Match() method on the url string.